# modal popup appears on screen on click of every usercontrol

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have multiple usercontrols in my home.aspx page.In the `Header.ascx` I have `button imgbtnCreateAccount`,On Click of this button modal popup appears on screen.

Now apart from this  I have Product search User control `ProductSearch.ascx`.I am retrieving data from database for both the usercontrols. In `producdtsearch.ascx` page I have label, textbox and submit button.

**If I leave textbox blank and press enter,it gives me required field validator which is fine,but when I type something in textbox and press enter it gives me modal popup which should not happen.It appears for all the other usercontrols which is textboxes in it.I have tried adding default button to the panel in which modal popup appears,but still nogo.Also tried changing the text property of imgbtnCreateAccount,still no go**.

I also tried to `set tetbox property to autopostback=true`,but what haapens is that, the background of modal popup blinks for a second and then goes off. Modal popup should only appear on click of imgbtnCreateAccont which is `Header.ascx` page and nwhile entering tect in any of the textboxes of other usercontrols.Kindly suggest the resolution.

Comment: did you mention TargetControlID="your control name"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved as i added panel and inside the panel i have div which contains table.there is button in table.i have set the default button property of panel to this button name and the issue got resolved.